# How to get Scheme from uri string without it?

Tags: c#, string, http, https

I want to get the correct scheme from a simple DNS string. How can I do this in C#?

---

Example:

I have this: `google.com`

I want to get this: `https://www.google.com`

---

But some other sites like this: `msn.com`

I want to get this: `http://www.msn.com`

Comment: Very interesting question; what defines 'correct scheme'? you could write a logic that does a portcheck on 443, if that succeeds - return 'https:', then check on 80 and if that succeeds - return 'http://'; but that a) doesn't guarantee there is anything there. b) will result in at least n calls for n addresses. What is your use case?

Comment: nice answer. Well, my use case is for endpoint users who don't know what is http and https. I want to make it automatic :D

Comment: how many users? how many addresses? will your application have unrestricted direct internet access? will it have to also work behind proxy in some cases?

Comment: many many nontechnical users. based on their location it may have unrestricted or not. yes some of them are working behind proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a database of common host names and their protocols you cannot do this. A URL has a protocol, a host, and a path. eg. `http://google.com/` tells you it's protocol is `http`, it's host is `google.com` and the path is `/`.

There are non standard conventions for http and that is that www `www.x.com` indicates `http://www.x.com/` and that `x.com` from 1999 means `http://x.com/` (but not `http://wwww.x.com/` so it requires a DNS entry).

With this logic `google.com` becomes `http://google.com/` and `msn.com` becomes `http://msn.com/`.

Usually the hosts redirect you to what they use as standard. eg. in Norway `http://google.com/` redirects me to `https://www.google.no/` but you cannot from `google.com` assume `https://www.google.no/`.

I'm no C# programmer so this a C# compatible Algol that might need some idiomatic retouch:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

class URLTest
{    
    // Return true on any string that starts with alphanumeric 
    // chars before ://.
    // hasProto("telnet://x.com") => true
    // hasProto("x.com/test") => false
    static bool hasProto(String url)
    {
       return Regex.IsMatch(url, "^\\w+://");
    }

    // Return true for any string that contains a / that does
    // have a / as it's previous or next char.
    // hasPath("http://x.com") => false
    // hasPath("x.com/") => true
    static bool hasPath(String url)
    {
       return Regex.IsMatch(url, "[^/]/(?:[^/]|$)");
    }

    // Adds http:// if URL lacks protocol and / if URL lacks path
    static String stringToURL(String str)
    {
        return ( hasProto(str) ? "" : "http://" ) + 
           str + 
           ( hasPath(str) ? "" : "/" );
    }
}
```

Comment: what does regex mean? what does it do?

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee It's short for [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions). Regexps are strings that notate a search pattern (wildcards on stereoids). Almost every language has them today and it saves time since it's very expressive. eg. `hasProto` will return `True` on any string that starts with alphanumeric chars before `://`. eg `telnet://`.

Comment: Please add comments like the edit I made to your code.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee Done. It was rejected because you edited in a question (second comment).